# Dismiss modal view and call initial view controller

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, modalviewcontroller

this is my problem. 
I have a tab bar, in the last tab I load a modal view. When I dismiss the modal view the app returns in the last tab of the tab bar. But instead I'd like that the app returns on the first tab of the tab bar (the initial view). 
if I dismiss the modal view the code that I insert after (to call initial view controller) is not taken in account. Can you offer me a solution? Thank you.

The code that I use is:

```
  [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
  InitialViewController* controller = (InitialViewController*)[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Initial"];
  [self presentViewController:controller animated:NO completion:nil];
```

Comment: "if I dismiss the modal view the code that I insert after (to call initial view controller) is not taken in account" Well, that's not true, so you must be doing something wrong. Why do you not show your code so we can make suggestions as to what it might be?

Comment: Ok I'm wrong, the code is taken in account, but I have a crash and the error is: Attempting to begin a modal transition from UINavigationController to InitialViewController while a transition is already in progress. Wait for viewDidAppear/viewDidDisappear to know the current transition has completed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are doing is not "returning" to the tab bar. Instead, you are *presenting* a completely *new* tab bar. Now you have *two* tab bar interfaces. Don't do that.This is sufficient to dismiss:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

To change tabs, you need a *reference* to the *existing* tab bar controller (not a *different* one). Then you can just say:

```
[theTabBarController setSelectedIndex:0];
```

If you know for a fact that you want to do that when you return from the modal controller, you can even do that at the time you *present* the modal controller.

Comment: Ok I understand but if I use this code I have no effect and after the dismiss the app returns in the last tab   [self presentViewController:navController animated:NO completion:nil];
UITabBarController *tabController = (UITabBarController*)[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TabBar"];
[tabController setSelectedIndex:0];

Comment: Ok! The solution is:                                             [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
[self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:0];